# How to integrate Opencv in Django rest frame

Tags: python, django, opencv

I have a simple opencv file that converts frames to video. I fetch video from Django db and convert to frame.

Now my  question is how can I save the converted frames in the directory where my video is.?

I get this error when I try to use the `uoload_to` function as a save path in the `video_to_frame` function
`cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(upload_to,'new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)`

`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function`

**Upload directory**

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename.lower())
    return f"SmatCrow/{instance.id}/{filename}"
```

**Model.py**

from .utils import video_to_frame

```
class MyVideo(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyVideo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) 
        tfile.write(self.videofile.read())
        vid = video_to_frame((tfile.name))
```

**Opencv**

```
def video_to_frame(video):
    today = date.today()
    d = today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
    cap= cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    i=1
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        if i%10 == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(upload_to,'new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)
        i+=1
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you need to call `upload_to` with arguments so it can return the filename, as it is, it's just a function. I don't know exactly what that'd look like, but `upload_to(instance, "somefilename.jpg")`

Comment: @Macattack the filename comes from a user who uploads a video file.. I can't hardcode any value for the filename

Comment: ok, well, you can pass in the filename, but, the problem remains the same. You've got the function `upload_to` that you're not calling, you're just passing as an argument to `os.path.join` and it can't join a function and a string.